# xpath: return value within an element found by preceeding value

Tags: python, xpath

Apologies for weird title (hard to explain). Here is my HTML:

```
<p>
  <strong>Date:</strong> May 12, 2015
</p>
```

Basically, I want to extract the date (`May 12, 2015`). I've come up with:

```
print advisory.xpath('//p/strong[text()="Date:"]')[0].text
```

But that naturally returns `Date:`. Any idea how to traverse to the parent, skip w/e is in the strong tag and return the rest?

Comment: What if you inverse the regex? everything inside `p` other than strong?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso Sure, but first tell me how to get everything inside `p`, that is my real problem.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, since the date text is actually the after-text of `<strong>` element, you can use `tail` attribute like this:

```
   [2]: s = '''<root><p><strong>Date:</strong> May 12, 2015</p></root>'''

In [3]: from lxml import etree as ET

In [4]: tree = ET.fromstring(s)

In [5]: tree.xpath('//p/strong[text()="Date:"]')[0].tail
Out[5]: ' May 12, 2015'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make the conditional a bit bigger

```
print advisory.xpath('//p[strong/text()="Date:"]/text()')[0]
```

Comment: Weird, that returns nothing despite looking correct.

Comment: How about `starts-with()`: `//p[starts-with(strong, "Date")]`?

Comment: @alecxe That also returns nil. Strange.

Comment: Ha, it was the `text()` that was being problematic. These both work: `advisory.xpath('//p[starts-with(strong, "Date:")]/text()')` and `advisory.xpath('//p[strong/text()="Date:"]/text()')`. If you modify your answer to add this, I can accept it :-) Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: I had considered doing that initially but figured the other way would work. Maybe its because the text is after the node.